# Keycloak get excepation when evaluating JavaScript-Based Policy

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I create simple policy following [this guide](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/authorization_services/topics/policy/js-policy.html):

```js
var identity = $evaluation.getIdentity();

if (identity.hasRole('view_device')) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

And associate this policy with the particular resource using permission.

But when I try to test my permission I got next error in server logs:

```java
11:42:05,172 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-44) RESTEASY002020: Unhandled asynchronous exception, sending back 500: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error evaluating JS Policy [Check role].
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:168)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.asynchronousExceptionDelivery(SynchronousDispatcher.java:437)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.AbstractAsynchronousResponse.internalResume(AbstractAsynchronousResponse.java:191)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.Servlet3AsyncHttpRequest$Servlet3ExecutionContext$Servle3AsychronousResponse.resume(Servlet3AsyncHttpRequest.java:114)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.entitlement.EntitlementService$1.onError(EntitlementService.java:125)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.permission.evaluator.IterablePermissionEvaluator.evaluate(IterablePermissionEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.permission.evaluator.DefaultPermissionEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultPermissionEvaluator.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.entitlement.EntitlementService.getAll(EntitlementService.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:107)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:133)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error evaluating JS Policy [Check role].
    at org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.js.JSPolicyProvider.evaluate(JSPolicyProvider.java:51)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.policy.evaluation.DefaultPolicyEvaluator.lambda$createDecisionConsumer$4(DefaultPolicyEvaluator.java:119)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.policy.evaluation.DefaultPolicyEvaluator.evaluatePolicies(DefaultPolicyEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.policy.evaluation.DefaultPolicyEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultPolicyEvaluator.java:75)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.permission.evaluator.IterablePermissionEvaluator.evaluate(IterablePermissionEvaluator.java:46)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: $evaluation.getIdentity is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.js.JSPolicyProvider.evaluate(JSPolicyProvider.java:49)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: <eval>:1 TypeError: $evaluation.getIdentity is not a function
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:185)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:172)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.lookup(Undefined.java:102)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:106)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:253)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$7$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn
```

I didn't change any default configurations and role view_device was created. If someone ran into the same error, please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: It was the typo in keycloak documentation.
So, in order to javascript policy be evaluated without errors, the method `getIdentity` should be called on the object `context`:

```js
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var identity = context.getIdentity();

if (identity.hasRole('view_device')) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

Comment: Can you open an ticket for the documentation typo here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK ? Thanks !

Comment: I got identity.hasRole is not a function error. Any idea? I even copied your code, and the same error...